# Reduce a list using lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, reduce

I need to write several functions like this. Is there a better way to write this function using lambda in one line or so.

```
def is_digital(offers):
    for offer in offers:
        digital = True if 'digital' in offer and offer['digital'] else False
        if digital:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: `lambda offers: any(offer.get('digital') for offer in offers)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `any` for this.

```
def is_digital(offers):
    return any(offer.get('digital') for offer in offers)
```

Or if you want to remove the full function definition and just use a lambda (not the best idea), you could do this:

```
is_digital = lambda offers: any(offer.get('digital') for offer in offers)
```

Thanks to jonrsharpe's comment for reminding me that `.get` is a thing.

Comment: Worth noting that using a ternary to set `True` or `False` and then *separately* testing the result is just weird...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, I was very confused by that.

Answer (score 2):

As for me following way to check is more readable and explicit:

```
def is_digital(offers):
    return any(map(lambda x: x.get('digital', False), offers))
```

you can even throw out default 'False', because 'None' is default return value if no specified key was found. But I think the code will become less explicit.

```
def is_digital(offers):
    return any(map(lambda x: x.get('digital'), offers))
```

The choice is your. =)